# no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std.. '

Tags: c++, string, loops, vector, c++14

The question I am solving states: I have to take **T** test cases. For each test case I have to take string as an input, then I need to arrange the input string as: *string at even position {double space} string at odd position* (example: *input* - StackOverflow, *output* - **Sakvrlw** **tcOefo**). I've written the following code where I am taking input for all test cases and storing it in a vector. Then I am assigning the elements of vector to another declared string s.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
     int T,i;
     cout << "Enter no. of test cases: ";
     cin >> T;

     vector<string> v;
     vector<string> odd;
     vector<string> even;
     string str;

     for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        cin >> str;
        v.push_back(str);
     }


     string s;

     for(i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        s = v.at(i);

        for(i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
            if(i==0){
                even.push_back(s[i]);  //*This is where I am getting error*.
            }else if(i==1){
                odd.push_back(s[i]);
            }else{
                if(i%2==0){
                    even.push_back(s[i]);
                }else{
                    odd.push_back(s[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<even.size(); i++){
            cout << even.at(i);
        }

        cout << "  ";

        for(i=0; i<odd.size(); i++){
            cout << odd.at(i);
        }

        cout << endl;

        even.clear();
        odd.clear();
        s.clear();
     }


     return 0;
}
```

While compiling the above code I'm getting `"no matching error for call std::vector..."`. 
***What exactly am I doing wrong?***

Comment: `even` is a character of strings and `s[i]` is not a string. Please in clude the compelte error message in the question, it should tell you what is wrong in the code, and if you dont understand it you could ask what it means, but in any case you should include it in the question

Comment: Why are you not showing the complete error message - the very thing that can help us help you?

Comment: If this is Visual Studio please copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab. The error message in the Errors List is often abbreviated and not in a good format for copy / paste of text.

Answer (score 5):

I am getting the following error when compiling your code:

`main.cpp:34:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector >::push_back(char&)’`.

This happens because `even` is a `vector<string>`, and `s[i]` is a `char`. You are trying to insert a char into a vector of strings, and that is not possible, as they are different types.

If I understood your problem properly, `even` and `odd` must both be either `vector<char>` or `string`, **not** `vector<string>`.

Change the declarations to:

```
string odd;
string even;
```

This also allows you to replace the printing:

```
for(i=0; i<even.size(); i++) {
    cout << even.at(i);
}
```

With:

```
cout << even;
```

Comment: "*that is not possible, as they are different types*" - more accurately, it is not possible only because `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts a single `char` as its sole input. But you can manually constructor a `std::string` that holds a single `char` and then `push_back()` that string, eg: `even.push_back(string(1, s[i]));` or `even.push_back(string(&s[i], 1));`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @Manish Jha,

So `s[i]` is a `char`

> `s` is a `std::string` or an array of `char`s

The method must be `push_back(std::string&)` not `push_back(std::char&)`

The class template method `std::vector::push_back(T&)` is kind of "specialized" when you initialized your even/odd vector so, either append a `std::string` to `std::vector<std::string>` or a `char` to `std::vector<char>`

Otherwise, there is no maching for call the method `std::vector<T>::push_back(T&)`

Hope i answered correctly to your waitings, if there are any errors, please notify me.